# Mariadb connection through proxy is not working

Tags: mysql, proxy, mariadb, haproxy, galera

I'm new to this whole thing, so please be nice...

I'm using HAProxy as a proxy for multiple things, but the issue that keeps coming back is that I want to use a proxy to connect to a Mariadb Galera cluster. I'm using keepalived to assign a virtual IP, on which the proxy should then listen and balance the connections to the databases. Current status is:

3 machines, each running a set of (slightly modified, only the necesary stuff) keepalived, HAProxy and MariaDB (with Galera enabled).

Their IPs are 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3, virtual IP assigned by keepalived is 10.0.0.9.

HAProxy listens on 3310, then balances to 3306 to the other machines (since the machines running HAProxy also run the database, that's why I use non-default port).

ISSUE: I'm using a no-password test user "lol" with no privileges, connecting from 10.0.0.1 (which also has 10.0.0.9 assigned atm). I'll post the rest below.

```
mysql -u lol #connects
mysql -P 3310 -u lol #connects
mysql -h 10.0.0.9 -u lol #connects
mysql -h 10.0.0.9 -u lol #from 10.0.0.2, connects
mysql -h 10.0.0.9 -P 3310 -u lol #hangs a while, then spits out this message:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11
```

Why does this happen? My firewall is (for now) completely open, so that should not be the issue. I am including config files for MariaDB, keepalived and HAProxy below. (I purposefuly deleted unnecesary comments from the config files)

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf (due to my way of installing, there are no other meaningful config files for MariaDB, but feel free to ask)

```
[server]

[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#

user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
lc-messages             = en_US
skip-external-locking

#skip-name-resolve

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

#
# * Fine Tuning
#

#key_buffer_size        = 128M
#max_allowed_packet     = 1G
#thread_stack           = 192K
#thread_cache_size      = 8
#myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64

#
# * Logging and Replication
#

#general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log            = 1


log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time        = 10
#log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan,explain
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#min_examined_row_limit = 1000

#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
#max_binlog_size        = 100M

#
# * SSL/TLS
#

#ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/cacert.pem
#ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
#ssl-key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#require-secure-transport = on

character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * InnoDB
#

#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G


[embedded]


[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.5]

[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3"
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0
# any cluster name
wsrep_cluster_name="MariaDB_Cluster"
# own IP address
wsrep_node_address="10.0.0.1"
```

/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf (I only included the meaningful part, there are other VRRPs set up, also other machines are configured as slaves with lower priorities, keepalived shouldn't be the issue here, just adding it to clarify)

```
...
vrrp_instance VRRP2 {
    state MASTER
    interface ens19
    virtual_router_id 111
    priority 200
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1011
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.0.0.9/24
    }
}
...
```

/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg (other things are set up here as well, excluding those)

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

frontend galera
    bind :3310
    default_backend mariadb

backend mariadb
    balance leastconn
    option mysql-check user lol
    server srv1 10.0.0.1:3306 check
    server srv2 10.0.0.2:3306 check
    server srv3 10.0.0.3:3306 check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer. The issue was, that I needed to add `mode tcp` to both the frontend and backend of the database. Now it's working as expected, if there will be any additional issues, I will comment on this answer. There are more things that depend on this.